# Dot notation request handling in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class (Not `ModelSerializer`) that needs to take a list of dot notation configuration from the request:

```
class ConfigurationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a_value= serializers.CharField(
        required=False,
        source='a.value',
    )
```

I thought by specifying the `source` attribute, the serializer will know `a.value` in the `request.data` will represent `a_value` in the `ConfigurationSerializer`.

But when I run the serializer.is_value(), I don't see any data inside serializer.data:

```
def post(self, request):
   serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
   if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
      print(serializer.data) #-----> this is empty
```

Is it the correct way to do it? How can I translate the dot notation from the request object to serializer?

Comment: The `source` parameter represents attributes or methods on the related `model` (included in the meta of *ModelSerializer*).

Comment: Thanks @AmirAfianian, then I think the source attribute is an no op for my Serializer class and I need to do manually mapping. Is it correct?

Comment: In your case yes. Could you explain more about how your input data look like and what do you want to do with it?